# Connectivity issue to connect Oracle DB from python apps using pyodbc

Tags: python, python-3.x, oracle, pyodbc

I'm trying to connect to a Oracle XE database from my python application using pyodbc module.
**Below are the code:**

```
import pyodbc;

conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in XE};DBQ=localhost:1521/xe;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx');
conn = pyodbc.connect('DSN=myOracleXEDSN;UID=xxxx;PWD=xxxx');
cursor = conn.cursor();

cursor.execute("select * from customer");
```

I also set up the ***Oracle DSN*** from **ODBC data source Administrator** Tool as follow and tested it with connection successful message

```
Data Source Name: myOracleXEDSN
Driver Name: Oracle in XE
TNS Service Name: XE
UserID: xxxx
Password: xxxx
```

But I'm getting the following message while run the python app:

```
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={Oracle in XE};DBQ=localhost:1521/xe;UID=system;PWD=sayan123');
pyodbc.InterfaceError: ('IM002', '[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I am not getting what I miss here as I'm new to use pyodbc module to connect to DB. please help me out.
python version:- 3.6
pyodbc version: 4.x

Comment: Call `pyodbc.drivers()` and verify that "Oracle in XE" is in the list of returned driver names.

Comment: @gord-thompson Yes  "Oracle in XE" is not shown in pyodbc driver list.
How can I register  "Oracle in XE" in pyodbc driver list?

Comment: What does `print("running as {0}-bit".format(struct.calcsize("P") * 8))` say?